# rsync --ignore-times parameter not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bash, backup, rsync

I want to implement a comprehensive backup script based on `rsync`, so I'm just experimenting now to decide the correct parameters based on my requirement. Basically, I want that any changed file should be copied from source to destination, regardless of its modification time (ie. whether or not source file is older/newer than destination file, it should be copied if the contents differ). However, it isn't working:

```
../src/test.txt
../dst/test.txt
```

Above is the folder structure. When I first ran the below command for first time, it copied the `test.txt` from src to dst folder.

```
rsync -avh --ignore-times src/ dst/
```

Then, I modified the contents of src/test.txt and ran above command again, and this time too it copied the updated file to dst folder.

However, I then modified the test.txt in dst folder, and ran above command, but this time, it didn't work and didn't copy the file from src/ to dst/ folder. But considering [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124101/43159), it should have worked as I've added the `--ignore-times` parameter.

Is this a bug with Ubuntu, or am I doing something wrong? What parameter should I add so that the file will be always copied from source to destination when the contents differ (even when the destination file is newer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--archive` equals -rlp**t**goD  while **-t** means

```
-t, --times
    This tells rsync to transfer modification times along with the files and update them on the remote system
```

But you could combine that with --no-OPTION like this

```
rsync -avh --no-t --ignore-times src/ dst/
```

and it should work perfectly

---

EDIT: actually the `--ignore-times`is superfluous, this is enough

```
rsync -avh --no-t src/ dst/
```

Comment: For some reason, `--no-t` does not prevent the tag 'T' to appear, even with `--ignore-times`.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit, what do you mean ?? What is a tag in this context ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear. I was referring to the 'T' tag under transfer. If you look for ' T ' (beware the two spaces) in the man page, it says: `An  alternate  value  of T means that the modification time will be set to the transfer time, which happens when a file/symlink/device is updated without --times and when a symlink is changed and the receiver  can't set its time.  (Note: when using an rsync 3.0.0 client, you might see the s flag combined with t instead of the proper T flag for this time-setting failure)` I was not able to make rsync to **really** ignore times (no reporting this).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the `--archive` or `a` mode doesn't seem to work with the `--ignore-times` or `--checksum` parameters. However, the simple recursive copy mode (`--recursive` or `r`). So in my case, the following did the job perfectly:

```
rsync -vcr src/ dst/
```